# How to locate file of wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

I am a real newbie with wordpress. I need to quickly find out the filename for a particular url.

Let's say my URL is

http://example.co.uk/account/membership-levels/

Where will the .php or .html file **most likely be**? In themes folder?
w
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depending on your theme, this could be a number of .php files. Likely... single.php? Maybe page.php? Or it could be a templated page - what theme are you using?

Comment: I am using OpenEstate theme. Still can't really find that file:/

Comment: It would be in wp-content > themes > OpenEstate > single.php or page.php

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't have a 1:1 relation between content and templates. On some minimalist themes you could have a single php template in your themes folder (`wp-content/themes/themename/single.php`) to display all your articles.

Depending on your permalink structure, that link you are asking about is probably rendered using the `page.php` template, and if it isn't, then `single.php` should be the one. The only reason for editing a template is when you need to change the structure of all your posts. If you only need to edit one particular post or page, then you should just edit the content.

To edit the content, you need to log into your dashboard (`wp-admin`) and look for that entry among the pages or posts section.

Many themes will show an edit icon next to the posts title if you read it while logged on your dashboard, so you can skip searching for it in the backend.